# Is a suggested improvement to a question considered an "answer"?

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, not-an-answer

**Original Question**

I have the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53070192/vba-connection-range-count-incorrect-with-second-window-maximized/53162646#53162646). I've raised both the "Not An Answer" and "in need of moderator intervention" flags with the following explanation:

> This is not an answer, more a comment I guess... The original issue is
>   not the MsgBox(or even how to explain the issue) but the fact that the
>   Range.Count is returning 0. The original question is clear about that.
>   Can we move this to a comment?

But both of my tags we're declined:

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical
>   inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I'm struggling to understand why, when I look at the [following post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/185074/344389), that type of answer, it clearly falls into the "Clarify the existing question"(or actually in this case offers a suggested improvement to the existing question) category.

I very much appreciate the suggested improvement, but I do think that it doesn't constitutes an answer by [Stack Overflow's very definition](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), am I wrong?

Maybe this would fall into the "Any answer that gets the asker going in the right direction is helpful" category and would be considered an answer, but I don't feel that is the case, again maybe I'm wrong, where is the line here? What constitutes "right direction"?

**Why This Question is Unique**

I have reviewed the [following question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265552/when-to-flag-an-answer-as-not-an-answer), but neither the question nor the answer directly addresses the "suggested improvement" scenario that I believe this answer lies in.

I'm not interested, broadly speaking, in the when to use the "not an answer" tag. I believe I understand how to use that flag. My question addresses (what I believe to be correct) understanding and how it applies to this specific and uniquely distinct scenario that I have laid out above.

Comment: It looks to be a good faith attempt to answer the question.  That means it's definitely an answer.  Perhaps not the one you want, but it's still an answer.

Comment: @fbueckert I don't agree, if I break my leg(an know my leg is broken) and attempt to run across a soccer field, and cannot. I then go to the doctor and ask him how cross the field(with a broken leg), and he shows me a better way to determine my leg is broken, he has not made a good faith attempt to help me cross that field. He's shown me a better way to explain my issue, but I'm no closer to crossing that field then before I visited that doctor(and he knows that). Now if the doctor put my leg in a cast and gives me a wheelchair, he has helped me, but this answer falls into the first scenario.

Comment: @fbueckert maybe I'm missing something(I think I am) could you explain why you believe that is a "attempt to answer the question"? Much Thanks :)

Comment: I agree that's not what you're asking, but it takes a respectable amount of effort to surface that; most of your question is focused on how the MessageBox doesn't seem to be doing what you want, instead of your actual problem.  So it stands to reason that readers will twig on that, and provide an alternate method to debug.  If that's not the kind of answers you want, I'd recommend editing to focus on the specific issue, instead of why your debugging is failing.

Comment: Ahhh I see, yes sorry it was so confusing, good suggestion, I've updated the question so that it's not so confusing.

Comment: @yivi I actually reviewed that question that you mentioned before writing this ticket and found no reference either in the question or the answer as to how this applies in the my specific scenario. I don't believe that a broad based clarification to the way that "Not an Answer" works necessarily precludes ALL questions related to specific implementations of this flag, especially one's unique in there specificity, or completely lacking coverage in the original broad based question/answer set.

Comment: I do believe it's covered. It's a wrong answer, but it's an answer. Downvote and move on. Have you downvoted the answer? Maybe you should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like they simply didn't understand what you were actually asking about, and posted an answer under that incorrect assumption.  That's not "not an answer", that's just an incorrect answer.  You should not be deleting answers because you think they *fail* to answer the question, that's what downvotes are for, but rather, because they are not actually attempts to answer the question.  That answer appears to be trying to solve what they interpreted the problem you were asking about to be, and so the flag was correctly declined.

Comment: Hmm, good point, I guess that's true. Though it really depends on the intention of the original poster, which I really don't know. You believe that it "looks like" they didn't understand. I would concur with that statement, I always give people the benefit of the doubt on these sort of things :)